# Gitlab ci - Fetch files present in all commits during ci

Tags: php, git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, cicd

Good morning,

I want to do tests with PHP Code Sniffer on the php files added or modified in my present commits when I trigger my gitlab ci after a merge request.

I tried several options, example:

- git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r $CI_COMMIT_SHA
- git diff-tree --name-only --no-commit-id $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_SHA
- git diff --name-only --diff-filter=ACMRT ${COMMIT_HASH}^!

I can't find the right command to fetch the files returned when my CI executes the git pull:

```
git pull origin ${CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME}
Updating 123abcd..1ab2c3d4
Fast forward
  superScript.php | 11 +++++++++++
  superScript2.php | 11 +++++++++++
  superScript3.php | 11 +++++++++++
  3 file changed, 11 inserts(+)
```

I would like to know :

```
superScript.php
superScript2.php
superScript3.php
```

thank you in advance, have a nice day